# Raven connection java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress

Tags: java, log4j2, sentry

I have very basic program that connects to PostgreSQL database and tests if Sentry logging works.

But I can't shut it down gracefully.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
package com.sample;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        logger.error("Random error");
        logger.trace("Exiting application.");
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

```
2015-12-13 16:13:31,914 pool-1-thread-1 ERROR An exception occurred while closing the Raven connection java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.remove(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:82)
    at java.lang.Runtime.removeShutdownHook(Runtime.java:239)
    at net.kencochrane.raven.connection.AsyncConnection.close(AsyncConnection.java:92)
    at net.kencochrane.raven.Raven.closeConnection(Raven.java:112)
    at net.kencochrane.raven.log4j2.SentryAppender.stop(SentryAppender.java:303)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.stop(AbstractConfiguration.java:313)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.stop(LoggerContext.java:303)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext$1.run(LoggerContext.java:262)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry$1.run(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.run(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

BTW, setting `raven.async.gracefulshutdown` to false doesn't help.

Project homepage https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with raven-java itself, I've created pull request and It now fixed.

https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/pull/166

You can use latest Sentry like this:

```
<repository>
    <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
    <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.kencochrane.raven</groupId>
        <artifactId>raven-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```